# I am trying to make my dice game so that instead of it changing one of numbers of the dice each roll it changes all of them

Tags: python, python-3.x, dice

So the problem is in line 9 through 32. It outputs say "3 0 0" then "3 4 0" then "3 4 6". Instead it should say "3 4 6" then it could be "6 1 2". I know it's to do with the numRolled variable and the way it loops with that but I cannot think where else to put it.

I've tried putting numRolled = 0 at the end of the "for i in range(3)" but that just makes it so that only the first number changes. I've tried making the numbers into a single variable list but I am not really confident with coding in lists so I decided to go with what I have here.

```
def DiceGame():

  numRolled = 1
  RunScore = 0
  Roll1 = 0
  Roll2 = 0
  Roll3 = 0
  #rolls the 3 dice 100 times
  for x in range(100): 
    numRolled = 0
    #rolls the 3 dice
    for i in range(3):
      score = rdm.randint(1,6)
      numRolled += 1
      #assigns score to each die
      if numRolled == 1:
        Roll1 = score
      if numRolled == 2:
        Roll2 = score
      if numRolled == 3:
        Roll3 = score

      if Roll1 == Roll2 and Roll1 == Roll3:
        RunScore += 100
      else:
        DiceTot = Roll1 + Roll2 + Roll3
      # If Total of Die MOD 2 == 0 then Running score += Dice Total 
      if DiceTot % 2 == 0:
        RunScore += DiceTot
      else:
        RunScore -= DiceTot  
      print(Roll1, Roll2, Roll3)
      print(RunScore)
```

As I said above, it outputs say "3 0 0" then "3 4 0" then "3 4 6". Instead it should say "3 4 6" then it could be "6 1 2"

Comment: move those prints away from that second forloop ...

Comment: `def roll(n): return [random.randint(1, 6) for i in range(n)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
def game: 
    forlopp:
        forloop:
            print()
            print()
```

to this

```
def game: 
    forlopp:
        forloop:
        print()
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Move everything not related to *individual* dice rolls out of the first loop:

```
  for x in range(100): 
    numRolled = 0
    #rolls the 3 dice
    for i in range(3):
      score = rdm.randint(1,6)
      numRolled += 1
      #assigns score to each die
      if numRolled == 1:
        Roll1 = score
      if numRolled == 2:
        Roll2 = score
      if numRolled == 3:
        Roll3 = score

    ####
    # Here the code below has been un-indented and removed from the range(3) loop
    ####

    if Roll1 == Roll2 and Roll1 == Roll3:
      RunScore += 100
    else:
      DiceTot = Roll1 + Roll2 + Roll3


      #####
      # Note: I have indented the following block to put it inside
      #       this "else" clause, so that it can use "DiceTot" reliably.
      #####

      # If Total of Die MOD 2 == 0 then Running score += Dice Total 
      if DiceTot % 2 == 0:
        RunScore += DiceTot
      else:
        RunScore -= DiceTot  
    print(Roll1, Roll2, Roll3)
    print(RunScore)
```

That should fix the code.

However, this would be easier using lists. You can generate a list of 3 dice rolls like this:

```
rolls = []
for _ in range(3):
  rolls.append(rdm.randint(1,6))
```

It can also be written as a list comprehension instead:

```
rolls = [rdm.randint(1,6) for _ in range(3)]
```

Whichever you do, you can then generate your statistics more easily:

```
if all(roll == rolls[0] for roll in rolls):
  RunScore += 100
else:
  DiceTot = sum(rolls)
  if DiceTot % 2 == 0:
    RunScore += DiceTot
  else:
    RunScore -= DiceTot
```

And you can print using the `join` function:

```
print(" ".join(rolls))
```

Using a list like this would allow you to get rid of the 3 dice roll variables and allow you to change the number of dice rolls on a whim without rewriting anything.